# Iterable hashtable implementation in C

Tags: beginner, algorithm, c, iterator, hash-map

I'm just finished my version of iterable hashtable. I want to review code in general (code style, data structures, remarks about the algorithms) and I have some questions:

1. I don't know how to implement errors in return-value way. So, I chose way when we contain error flag variable in struct. Is it correct?
2. What functions are missing in interface? Maybe `pop()` or something like this?
3. Where do I need includind headers like `stddef.h` or `string.h`? (e.g. I don't use functions from `string.h` in my header, do I need include it in `htable.h`?)

**htable.h**:

```
#ifndef HTABLE_H
#define HTABLE_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct node_t {
    void* el;
    struct node_t* nextp;
} node_t;

typedef enum hterror_t {
    HTE_OK,
    HTE_MEM_EXHAUST,
    HTE_REMOVE,
    HTE_TOTAL
} hterror_t;

typedef struct index_t index_t;

enum { HTABLE_SIZE = 8191 };
typedef struct htable_t {
    node_t*    table[HTABLE_SIZE];
    index_t*   indexes;
    hterror_t  err_f;

    uint32_t   (*hash)(void *);
    int32_t    (*cmp)(void *, void *);
} htable_t;

htable_t*  htable_create(uint32_t (*hash)(void *), int32_t (*cmp)(void *, void *));
node_t*    htable_lookup(htable_t* ht, void* el, bool create);
void       htable_remove(htable_t* ht, void* el);
void       htable_foreach(htable_t* ht, void (*fn)(node_t *, void *), void *arg);
void       htable_destroy(htable_t* ht);

#endif // HTABLE_H
```

**htable.c**:

```
#include "htable.h"

typedef struct index_t {
    size_t index;
    struct index_t* nextp;
} index_t;

htable_t* htable_create(uint32_t (*hash)(void *), int32_t (*cmp)(void *, void *))
{
    htable_t* htable = malloc(sizeof(htable_t));
    if (htable == NULL)
        return NULL;

    memset(htable->table, 0, sizeof(htable->table[0]) * HTABLE_SIZE);
    htable->indexes = NULL;
    htable->err_f   = HTE_OK;
    htable->hash    = hash;
    htable->cmp     = cmp;

    return htable;
}

node_t* htable_lookup(htable_t* ht, void* el, bool create)
{
    node_t*   tmp;
    uint32_t  h;

    h = ht->hash(el) % HTABLE_SIZE;
    for (tmp = ht->table[h]; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->nextp)
        if (ht->cmp(tmp->el, el) == 0)
            return tmp;

    if (create) {
        if (ht->table[h] == NULL) { /* if there's no node for hash h */
            index_t* ni = malloc(sizeof(index_t));
            if (ni == NULL) {
                ht->err_f = HTE_MEM_EXHAUST;
                return NULL;
            }
            ni->index = h;
            ni->nextp = ht->indexes;
            ht->indexes = ni;
        }

        node_t* newnode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        if (newnode == NULL) {
            ht->err_f = HTE_MEM_EXHAUST;
            return NULL;
        }
        newnode->el = el;
        newnode->nextp = ht->table[h];
        ht->table[h] = newnode;
    }

    return tmp;
}

void htable_remove(htable_t* ht, void* el)
{
    node_t*  p, * prev;
    uint32_t h;

    h = ht->hash(el) % HTABLE_SIZE;

    prev = NULL;
    for (p = ht->table[h]; p != NULL; p = p->nextp) {
        if (ht->cmp(p->el, el) == 0) {
            if (prev == NULL)
                ht->table[h] = p->nextp;
            else
                prev->nextp = p->nextp;
            free(p);
            return ;
        }
        prev = p;
    }

    ht->err_f = HTE_REMOVE;
}

void htable_foreach(htable_t* ht,
                    void (*fn)(node_t *, void *), void *arg)
{
    index_t* prev, * p;
    node_t*  cur_n;

    prev = NULL;
    for (p = ht->indexes; p != NULL; p = p->nextp) {
        if (ht->table[p->index] == NULL) {
            if (prev == NULL) {
                ht->indexes = p->nextp;
                free(p);
                p = ht->indexes;
            } else {
                prev->nextp = p->nextp;
                free(p);
                p = prev;
            }
        }

        for (cur_n = ht->table[p->index]; cur_n != NULL; cur_n = cur_n->nextp)
            fn(cur_n, arg);
    }
}

void htable_destroy(htable_t* ht)
{
    index_t* buf_i;

    for (; ht->indexes != NULL; ht->indexes = buf_i) {
        buf_i = ht->indexes->nextp;
        if (ht->table[ht->indexes->index] != NULL) {
            node_t* buf_n;
            for (; ht->table[ht->indexes->index] != NULL; ht->table[ht->indexes->index] = buf_n) {
                buf_n = ht->table[ht->indexes->index]->nextp;
                free(ht->table[ht->indexes->index]);
            }
        }

        free(ht->indexes);
    }

    free(ht);
}
```

Simple usage of htable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "htable.h"

/* ihash and icmp are needed for construct htable */
uint32_t ihash(void* y)
{
    uint32_t x = *(uint32_t *) y;
    x = ((x >> 16) ^ x) * 0x45d9f3b;
    x = ((x >> 16) ^ x) * 0x45d9f3b;
    x =  (x >> 16) ^ x;
    return x;
}

int32_t icmp(void* a, void* b)
{
    return *(int *) a - *(int *) b;
}

/* icopy, ifree and iprint are not necessary */
void* icopy(void* i)
{
    int* _i = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (_i == NULL)
        return NULL;
    *_i = *(int *) i;

    return _i;
}

void ifree(node_t* n, void* arg)
{
    (void) arg;
    if (n->el != NULL)
        free(n->el);
}

void iprint(node_t* np, void* arg)
{
    printf((char *) arg, (np == NULL) ? 0 : *(int *) np->el);
}

int main()
{
    htable_t* ht = htable_create(ihash, icmp);
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; ++i)
        htable_lookup(ht, icopy(&i), true);

    int k = 12;
    iprint(htable_lookup(ht, &k, false), "lookup: %d\n");
    ifree(htable_lookup(ht, &k, false), NULL);
    htable_remove(ht, &k);
    iprint(htable_lookup(ht, &k, false), "lookup: %d\n"); /* returns NULL */
    htable_foreach(ht, iprint, "foreach: %d\n");
    htable_foreach(ht, ifree, NULL); /* freeing memory that we allocated from the loop above */
    htable_destroy(ht);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please include code that calls these functions so that we can perform a better review?

Answer (score 3):

- Combining lookup and insertion functionality in one function looks like an unnecessary violation of SRP. I strongly recommend to separate them.
- Keeping the error inside the structure is indeed questionable. Notice that once you split lookup and insert, `return errcode;` becomes natural: every function besides `insert` would just return an error code, and `insert` would return `NULL` on failure.

  If you still want to keep the error flag, you should at least clear it in the beginning of any function which may set it, and provide a function to check it. As of now, the client must directly access `ht->err_f`, which breaks the encapsulation.
- Speaking of encapsulation, the standard practice is to forward declare `typedef struct htable_t htable_t;` in the `htable.h`, and define it in `htable.c`. The client has no business knowing how exactly the table is organized.
- `htable_foreach` apparently attempts to compact the list of indices. It is a very strange place to do so. Removing an index is more natural in `htable_remove`. Meanwhile, I am not sure what benefits does the list of indices provide.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

I saw this method (when we putting insert and lookup in one function) in book "The Practice of Programming" (c.2, p.56). Now I understand that way that used in the book is intended for concrete data, and not for abstract data.t.

I remove indices in `foreach()` function because I think it will be faster to remove items like this, rather than going through the list every time when we calling `remove()`. Also, if you don't need to iterate over the table, you'll never remove indieces, except the call function `destroy()`.

Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Comment: SRP acronym deserves definition/link

Comment: I think he meant The Single Responsibility Principle from SOLID